# Looking for software to seamlessly launch video clips in real time and in any order

Tags: video-player

Thanks in advance everyone. I'm looking for software that can replace our going-on-twenty-years-old custom solution from an employee who moved on to another job years ago.

We currently use a touchscreen to launch video clips for live presentations. Menus of thumbnails with titles allow presenters to select and play the video clips in any order, and our video server launches them fast enough that there's no delay between the clips - no black. Picture it like editing a video on the fly as you present, going from clip to clip in a way that looks like one continuous movie from the audience.

The problem is, this is all custom programmed from years ago. We can't change anything on our own, or even simply add a video file to an existing menu. We want something we can update on our own.

Even Windows has caught up with our interface *almost* as far as we need on our own. We tested using just Windows and launching the videos straight from folders instead of custom menus. The navigation is fine for our purposes but the videos launch too slowly - it's no longer seamless from the audience perspective.

A playlist isn't quite what we need, because during the presentation we sometimes cut clips off early or change the order depending on the needs one time to the next. Maybe if each presenter could have their own playlist, and one where we can seamlessly skip to the next clip partway through, that *might* also meet our end goal in a new way.

Any suggestions for flexible video playback that's seamless back to back? The current system is Windows 7, but the institution overall runs some MacOS and Win7-10 so that isn't a limit. We have a small budget too for getting the interface back in our control.

Comment: What is the size and amount of your videos? I'm asking because burning DVD ISOs (not the actual DVD disks) may be an option. Just give the DVD a start menu, map the ISO to a drive letter and use software like PowerDVD to play that 'disk'. It's a static solution though and limited to 4.7 (9.4) GB

Comment: We have over 300 (I'll need to count) short video clips at 1080p resolution, the largest files are 2 minutes long. I think the quantity may be more of a challenge than the storage space. 

I hadn't thought about DVD menus. Is there something about launching an ISO that's faster or more seamless? I assume if it's a disk image and not a real disk we could make them any size we need.

Comment: I suggested ISO because you would never get enough speed from a physical DVD. Whether DVD creation software will let you make ISO files larger than physical disks you would have to try out. I remember from CD burning days that you would get a warning for 'overburning' but you could do that.